# In the PubSub Framework, what content formats can an entry have?

Tags: cocoa, rss, publish-subscribe

What formats can an entry be read in? The only one I could find was `content.plainTextString`. Is there an HTML format? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is a lot old, but for future SO users here is the relevant documentation page:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Reference/PubSubReference/PSContent_h/Classes/PSContent/index.html

To answer the original question, Yes, there is an HTML format.

```
PSEntry *entry = someEntry; //someEntry is a PSEntry
entry.content.HTMLString;
```